# Show that the derivative of a normed polynomial, that only has real roots, isnt complex.

Tags: analysis, roots

Normed means that the coefficient of the highest term is $1$. This is a question on a test in analysis and I'm trying to understand the solution of one of our tutors. [image: I have uploaded it here]

I don't think a translation is essential for understanding it but just in case: it says "If $\alpha_1$ to $\alpha_n \in \mathbb R$ are the roots (listed with their multiplicities) of the normed polynomial $p$ then $p$ is given by the term.... with....
Specifically is ..... for every $x \in \mathbb R$"

I just have trouble finding out how to get this formula for $a_k$. I appreciate every answer!

Tömmel

Comment: `have trouble finding out how to get this formula for a_k` Those are just [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) in disguise. More important than the expressions themselves, the point is that if the leading coefficient is real (in particular $1\,$) and if all roots are real, then all coefficients are real as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over the complex numbers (which are algebraically closed) you know that $p(x)$ factors into linear polynomials, i.e. $$p(x) = c\Pi_i (x-\alpha_i)$$ in which the $\alpha_i$ are the roots of $p$ and $c$ is the leading coefficient of $c$.

Since we assume that $p(x)$ is "normed" (the usual term in English is monic) we know that $c = 1$

Thus we have simply $$p(x) = \Pi_i (x-\alpha_i)$$
in which the $\alpha_i$ are real.  We quickly see that $p(x)$, being the product of real linear polynomials, is a polynomial with real coefficients.  Taking its derivative also yields a polynomial with real coefficients.

The solution you provided gives explicit polynomial formulas for the coefficients of $p(x)$ in terms of its roots, but that's not really necessary.  The point is just that the real numbers are of course closed under multiplication and addition.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your answer! Does it matter that the polynomial is monic? Is the point of that condition that you can say "the real  numbers are closed under multiplication and addition, so the derivative cant be complex"? because you could choose a complex number for your variable c and the roots wouldnt change. the derivative would be complex though.

Comment: It's very important that the polynomial's leading coefficient is real! That it is monic will certainly suffice. 

Consider if $c$ above is imaginary.  Then by our reasoning that the reals are closed under addition and multiplication (indeed they constitute a field) we can say that $p(x) = c q(x)$ where $q$ is a polynomial with real coefficients. 
 Since a real number times a complex nonreal is a complex nonreal, $p(x)$ would be guaranteed to have no real coefficients at all.  Hence it's derivative would be the same way.